# Pass post id as a second segment in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would like to build the following url for artcles: http://mysite.com/articles/**ID**. Where the **ID** is the id of the article, which isn't constant of course. How can the be done using codeigniter? As I know the second segment should be the method name inside the controller...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its simple, Codeigniter have powerful url routing

```
 http://mysite.com/article/id
```

In your router

```
$route['articles/([0-9]+)'] = "controller_name/article/$1";
```

And in your controller

```
public function article($id) {
  //here your article id
  echo $id;
}
```

Also you need some url forwarding on .htaccess to forward all combinations to index.php

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

use codeigniter routing.

Add this in routing
$route['articles/(:num)'] = "articles/list/$1";

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html